# Router link in child component

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I have a RouteConfig in my top level app component defined like this:

```
@RouteConfig(const [
  const Route(path: '/admin', name: 'AdminSite', component: AdminSite),
  const Route(path: '/', name: 'ManagerSite', component: ManagerSite, useAsDefault: true),
])
```

And I have a child component that should hold the navigation links. I define the child component and in the template I used:

```
  <nav>
    <a *ngIf="authService.user?.is_admin" [routerLink]="['AdminSite']">Admin</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['ManagerSite']">Home</a>
  </nav>
```

If I put the links in the app component, everything works fine, but if I move them to the child component, the url in the browser address line updates when I click the link, but the router outlet doesn't change.

I searched through the docs but I can't figure out whats wrong. Can someone please explain what's going on?

Comment: Can you make a plunker with your problem?

Comment: I don't know how to setup angular-dart in plunker.

Comment: What component is "child component" a child component of?

Comment: Its a simple component with some navigation menu UI that is part of the top-level app component template.

Comment: If the link is in a component that is added statically to the AppComponent, then it should work like you have it. Are you using HashLocationStrategy?

Comment: I added ROUTER_PROVIDERS to providers and that was breaking it. Once I removed it it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you miss the following in child components, moving the `<a>(anchor)` tags won't work.

- import `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES`

  `import {RouteConfig, RouterOutlet, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';`
- Give the correct path to below

  `<a *ngIf="authService.user?.is_admin" [routerLink]="['AdminSite']">Admin</a>
   <a [routerLink]="['ManagerSite']">Home</a>`

something like this `['./ManagerSite']` or `['./AdminSite']`

Working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ktz1eVAzIzEOkTPqjmD2?p=preview)

In that plunker check this file `app/crisis-center/crisis-center.component.ts`

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to make the router link

```
<a [routerLink]="['/ManagerSite']">Home</a>
```

or

```
<a [routerLink]="['../ManagerSite']">Home</a>
```

if the `routerLink` is in the `AdminSite` or `ManagerSite` component, otherwise the router would try to navigate to a child route of the component that contains your "child component".